# Xamarin. Got an issue with loading mp3 to play via MediaPlayer: FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, android, file, audio, uri

I create an application for android via Monogame (C#). In order to reduce my .apk size I decied to don't use Content Pipeline for audio. I found that I can use raw mp3 with Song.FromUri() method. Using next code

```
Song mySong;
//...
mySong = Song.FromUri("track01", new System.Uri("audio.mp3", System.UriKind.Relative));
//...
MediaPlayer.Play(mySong);
```

I got and exception "Unhandled Exception: Java.IO.FileNotFoundException: track01" on

```
MediaPlayer.Play(mySong);
```

, but I have file "audio.mp3" in main folder.
[Solution Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNKMz.jpg)

Changing property "Build Action" to "None"/"Content"/"AndroidAsset" and "Copy to output directory" to "Copy always" didn't bring anything new.
I searched the solution, but it looks like nobody has the same problem or they solve it easily. The only similar problem I meet [here](http://techqa.info/programming/question/14418276/windows-phone-8-on-emulator---why-can%27t-i-play-audio-files), but their solution didn't help.
Do you have any ideas that can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about Song.FromUri Method, but this is how I'm using sound files.

```
        var player = new MediaPlayer();
        var fd = global::Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd("sounds/Wrong.mp3");
        player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
        {
            player.Start();
        };
        player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
        player.Prepare();
```

I have Kept my Wrong.mp3 in Assets/sounds Folder

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. I think it is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not a possibility to put the audio file into the resources?

If you open your project properties, there should be a resources tab. Within this tab, you should be able to add different values (strings, images, etc) including audio files. If you've added this here, it should be reachable through the resource manager.

Let me know if this works out!

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot do that, because there is not Resource tab in Android Xamarin project. There are only Application/Android Manifest/Android Options/Build/Build Events/Reference Paths. Btw, I checked that there is Resource tab in my Windows Forms application. Anyway, thanks for your answer.